# Listener for checkbox not being called

Tags: javascript, checkbox, event-listener

In my Javascript file, I have a listener for two different checkboxes, but they aren't being called when I check/uncheck them. Here is the html for the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ApproverCheckBox" id="@Approver[0]" checked/>@Approver[1]</li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="AccessorCheckBox" id="@entry[0]" checked/>@entry[1]</li>
```

here is the section in the Javascript file that isn't executing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //listener for accessor checkbox
    $('input[name=ApproverCheckBox]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //AddAccessor(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }
        else {
            //RemoveAccessor(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }

    });

    //listener for approver checkbox
    $('input[name=ApproverCheckBox]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //AddApprover(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }
        else {
            //RemoveApprover(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }

    });

});
```

I added alerts to them whilst testing...could someone shed some light please.

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/fJkpH/1/

Comment: The script works in js fiddle. IS the HTML created dynamicly?

Comment: I confirm it's working. Have you imported the jQuery library correctly?

Comment: When you create the HTML on the fly, you need to use https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JelleP the HTML is indeed created dynamically

Comment: @piacente.cristian the import is definitely correct, it is part of a shared layout declared in all pages including this one. I even manually added it just to be sure, but to no avail

Comment: @user2405469 if it is created dynamically,  maybe it happens because you add the events before you add the elements on the page, and the ready function in this case is useless. Try to add the events of onchange on your page once the elements have been created using firebug, and check if the events are triggered

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (place after adding HTML)

```
    //listener for accessor checkbox
    $(document).on('change','input[name=ApproverCheckBox]', function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //AddAccessor(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }
        else {
            //RemoveAccessor(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }

    });

    //listener for approver checkbox
    $(document).on('change','input[name=ApproverCheckBox]', function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //AddApprover(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }
        else {
            //RemoveApprover(this.id);
            alert("it is working");
        }

    });
```

Comment: I was just in the middle of trying this, I'll just add the function you have and come back to you

Comment: unfortunately this solution didn't work, it doesn't execute the listeners.

Comment: You can try to create the listener just after creating the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The document ready was never being called because of a wrongly added script with document ready that had an error inside it.